# MarkerCluster does not zoom when cluster clicked if it cannot reach a zoom level that will separate elements. How can I check for this?

Tags: leaflet, clustering, markers, leaflet-plugins

I have a map with a maximum zoom level of 18. It is possible to have data points that are so close together that they are still clustered at zoom 18, and it is also possible to have multiple data points at the exact same location (which, again, means they are still represented by a cluster at zoom 18).

I have noticed that when I am zoomed out and I click on a cluster that CAN be separated, the map zooms in until elements are separated. However, if I click on a cluster that CANNOT be separated at any allowed zoom level (as described above), the map does not zoom in.

In a 'clusterclick' listener function, is there some way to check whether this clusterclick is causing a zoom? I ask because I am trying to display a popup with info about all elements in the cluster, but only if those elements cannot be shown individually. Since the lack of automatic zooming is an indication of markerCluster "knowing" that the elements cannot be shown individually, I want to check whether the zoom is happening.

My code looks like this:

```
function addMapLayerToMap(geoJsonLayer, layerID) {
    // Leaflet marker cluster
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport({
        clusterPane: layerID.toString()
    });

    markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
        if (/*this clusterclick is not triggering a zoom in*/) {
            let outThing = [];
            let childMarkers = a.layer.getAllChildMarkers();
            let markerCounter = 0;

            outThing.push("<b>Elements too close to be viewed individually on map.</b><br />");

            childMarkers.every((marker) => {
                if (marker.feature.properties) {
                    markerCounter = markerCounter + 1;

                    if (markerCounter <= 10) {
                        if (markerCounter > 1) {
                            outThing.push("");
                        }

                        for (key in marker.feature.properties) {
                            outThing.push(key + ": " + marker.feature.properties[key]);
                        }

                        return true;
                    } else {
                        outThing.push("");
                        outThing.push("<b>Too many elements to list. See data grid page to view element details.</b>");

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            let outTot = "<div style='max-height:350px;height:100%;overflow-y:auto;'>" + outThing.join("<br />") + "</div>";

            map.openPopup(outTot, a.layer.getLatLng());
        }
    });

    // Add layer to cluster
    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    map.addLayer(markers);
}
```

Comment: When zoom on cluster click is not possible, spiderfy happens. So you want to prevent spiderify and open popup? Please edit your question and clarify this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It doesn't matter whether spiderfy happens or not, so I was able to modify the code to listen for spiderfy instead and it worked. I have a separate issue with spiderfy, so I will post that as a separate question.